# Solidity Yul push struct to dynamic array in storage

Tags: solidity, yul

So like the title says I'm trying to push a struct to a dynamic array with **yul**.

This is my code:

```
contract Spiral {
    struct Chunk {
        int256 x;
        int256 y;
    }
    Chunk[] public chunks;
    bytes1 directionB = 0x00;
    function addChunk() public {
        uint256 r;
        int256 x;
        int256 y;
        assembly {
            r := sload(0)
            x := sload(keccak256(sub(r, 1), 0x20))
            y := sload(add(keccak256(sub(r, 1), 0x20), 1))
        }
        // console.log("x: %s | y: %s", uint256(x), uint256(y));
        assembly {
            sstore(chunks.slot, add(sload(chunks.slot), 1))

            switch sload(directionB.slot)
            case 0x00 {
                sstore(keccak256(r, 0x20), add(x, 1))
                sstore(add(keccak256(r, 0x20), 1), y)
            }
            case 0x01 {
                sstore(keccak256(r, 0x20), x)
                sstore(add(keccak256(r, 0x20), 1), sub(y, 1))
            }
            case 0x02 {
                sstore(keccak256(r, 0x20), sub(x, 1))
                sstore(add(keccak256(r, 0x20), 1), y)
            }
            case 0x03 {
                sstore(keccak256(r, 0x20), x)
                sstore(add(keccak256(r, 0x20), 1), add(y, 1))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There was also some logic present that changes the value of `directionB`, but I omitted that part to keep it simple.

So I tried in this way to push the struct to the storage by firstly increasing the array size with
`sstore(chunks.slot, add(sload(chunks.slot), 1))`
and after
`sstore(keccak256(r, 0x20), add(x, 1))`
&
`sstore(add(keccak256(r, 0x20), 1), y)` 
to write the storage with the values of `x` and `y`.

After these operations when I try to call the chunks at any present index I get 0,
but if I console log with hardhat the `x` and `y` values it shows the correct ones.

So I'm kinda stuck, I could not find any appropriate answer to this so that's why I'm posting.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You used `keccak256` inappropriately: `keccak256(p, n)` has two arguments, the first is the memory position to start taking data from, the second is the length in memory. So you need to put the values you need to hash into memory first.

Also the storage layout for the array was messed up, have a look at this:

```
    function addChunk() public {
        uint256 r;
        int256 x;
        int256 y;
        assembly {
            // length of array
            r := sload(chunks.slot)
            
            // we put chunks.slot into memory since we need to hash the value
            // remember that an array is saved from keccak(chunks.slot)
            mstore(0x00, chunks.slot)
            let chunks_pt := keccak256(0x00, 0x20)

            // this points to the current last element
            // we do (r-1) since the last element is chunks[r-1]
            // also the multiplication by 2 is because every Chuck fills two slots
            let p := add(mul(sub(r, 1), 2), chunks_pt)

            // read the data onto the stack
            x := sload(p)
            y := sload(add(p, 1))
        }
        // console.log("x: %s | y: %s", uint256(x), uint256(y));
        assembly {
            // increase length
            let new_r := add(r, 1)
            sstore(chunks.slot, new_r)

            switch sload(directionB.slot)
            case 0x00 {
                // save as before but new length
                mstore(0x00, chunks.slot)
                let chunks_pt := keccak256(0x00, 0x20)
                let new_p := add(mul(r, 2), chunks_pt)

                // store new values
                sstore(new_p, add(x, 1))
                sstore(add(new_p, 1), y)
            }
            // write the other cases here ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot , this works